# Integral and limit with geometric factor

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, limits

I would like to calculate the following limit $$\lim_{x \to x_0}{\frac{log\left(\frac{1}{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^{x}{\frac{\sqrt{f(x)f(x_0)}}{f(u)}du}\right)}{\left(\int_{x_0}^{x}{\frac{1}{f(u)}du}\right)^2}}$$

where $f$ strictly positive and infinitely differentiable.

We can define the functions $$h(x)=\int_{x_0}^{x}{\frac{1}{f(u)}du}$$

and  $$h_1(x)=\sqrt{f(x)f(x_0)}h(x)$$

This the limit can be rewritten as

$$\lim_{x \to x_0}{\frac{log(\frac{h_1(x)-h_1(x_0)}{x-x_0})}{x-x_0}}\frac{x-x_0}{h_1(x)^2-h_1(x_0)^2}f(x)f(x_0)$$

Finally define $$h_2(x)=log(\frac{h_1(x)-h_1(x_0)}{x-x_0})$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x \to x_0}{\frac{h_2(x)-h_2(x_0)}{x-x_0}}\frac{x-x_0}{h_1(x)^2-h_1(x_0)^2}f(x)f(x_0)$$

where $h_2(x_0)$ is obtained by extending $h_2$ by continuity around $x_0$, which is $0$

I would like to conclude using the derivative slope definition but something is not adding up as I get and undefined behavior.

Comment: Am i missing something, why do you multiply with $$f(x) * f(x_{0})$$ at the end?

Comment: I fixed the definition of my integral. I multiplied both the numerator and the denominator by this number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculations might be a bit off but the idea should be OK. 
Let $b=-\frac{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}{f(x_{0})}$ and $c=\frac12\frac
{-f^{\prime\prime}(x_{0})f(x_{0})+2(f^{\prime}(x_{0}))^{2}}{(f(x_{0}))^{3}}$
and $d=\frac{1}{2}\left[  \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(x_{0})}{f(x_{0})}-\frac{1}
{2}\frac{(f^{\prime}(x_{0}))^{2}}{(f(x_{0}))^{2}}\right]  $. Use the following
Taylor's formulas
\begin{align*}
f(x)  & =f(x_{0})+f^{\prime}(x_{0})(x-x_{0})+o((x-x_{0})),\\
\frac{1}{f(x)}  & =\frac{1}{f(x_{0})}-\frac{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}{(f(x_{0}))^2
}(x-x_{0})+\frac12\frac{-f^{\prime\prime}(x_{0})f(x_{0})+2(f^{\prime
}(x_{0}))^{2}}{(f(x_{0}))^{3}}(x-x_{0})^{2}+o((x-x_{0})^{2})\\
(f(x))^{1/2}  & =(f(x_{0}))^{1/2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{f^{\prime}(x_{0})}
{(f(x_{0}))^{1/2}}(x-x_{0})\\
& +\frac{1}{2}\left[  f^{\prime\prime}(x_{0})(f(x_{0}))^{-1/2}-\frac{1}
{2}(f^{\prime}(x_{0}))^{2}(f(x_{0}))^{-3/2}\right]  (x-x_{0})^{2}
+o((x-x_{0})^{2})\\
\log(1+t)  & =t+o(t),
\end{align*}
to write
\begin{align*}
\int_{x_{0}}^{x}\frac{1}{f(u)}\,du  & =\frac{1}{f(x_{0})}\int_{x_{0}}
^{x}\left(  1+b(u-x_{0})+c(u-x_{0})^{2}+o((u-x_{0})^{2})\right)  \,du\\
& =\frac{1}{f(x_{0})}\left(  x-x_{0}+\frac{1}{2}b(x-x_{0})^{2}+\frac{1}
{3}c(x-x_{0})^{3}+o((x-x_{0})^{3})\right)
\end{align*}
and so
$$
\left(  \int_{x_{0}}^{x}\frac{1}{f(u)}\,du\right)  ^{2}=\frac{(x-x_{0})^{2}
}{f^{2}(x_{0})}\left(  1+\frac{1}{2}b(x-x_{0})+o((x-x_{0}))\right)  ^{2}
$$
while
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}}{\sqrt{f(x_{0})}}  & =1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{f^{\prime}(x_{0}
)}{f(x_{0})}(x-x_{0})\\
& +\frac{1}{2}\left[  \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(x_{0})}{f(x_{0})}-\frac{1}
{2}\frac{(f^{\prime}(x_{0}))^{2}}{(f(x_{0}))^{2}}\right]  (x-x_{0}
)^{2}+o((x-x_{0})^{2})
\end{align*}
and so
\begin{align*}
& \log\frac{\sqrt{f(x)f(x_{0})}}{x-x_{0}}\int_{x_{0}}^{x}\frac{1}{f(u)}\,du\\
& =\log\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}}{\sqrt{f(x_{0})}}\left(  1+\frac{1}{2}b(x-x_{0}
)+\frac{1}{3}c(x-x_{0})^{2}+o((x-x_{0})^{2})\right)  \\
& =\log\left(  1-\frac{1}{2}b(x-x_{0})+d(x-x_{0})^{2}+o((x-x_{0})^{2})\right)
\left(  1+\frac{1}{2}b(x-x_{0})+\frac{1}{3}c(x-x_{0})^{2}+o((x-x_{0}
)^{2})\right)  \\
& =\log\left(  1+d(x-x_{0})^{2}-\frac{1}{4}b^{2}(x-x_{0})^{2}+\frac{1}
{3}c(x-x_{0})^{2}+o((x-x_{0})^{2})\right)  \\
& =\left(  d-\frac{1}{4}b^{2}+\frac{1}{3}c\right)  (x-x_{0})^{2}
+o((x-x_{0})^{2})
\end{align*}
and so you get
\begin{align*}
{\frac{\log\left(\frac{1}{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^{x}{\frac{\sqrt{f(x)f(x_0)}}{f(u)}du}\right)}{\left(\int_{x_0}^{x}{\frac{1}{f(u)}du}\right)^2}}=& \frac{\left(  d-\frac{1}{4}b^{2}+\frac{1}{3}c\right)  (x-x_{0}
)^{2}+o((x-x_{0})^{2})}{\frac{(x-x_{0})^{2}}{f^{2}(x_{0})}\left(  1+\frac
{1}{2}b(x-x_{0})+o((x-x_{0}))\right)  ^{2}}\\
& =\frac{\left(  d-\frac{1}{4}b^{2}+\frac{1}{3}c\right)  +o(1)}{\frac{1}
{f^{2}(x_{0})}\left(  1+\frac{1}{2}b(x-x_{0})+o((x-x_{0}))\right)  ^{2}
}\rightarrow f^{2}(x_{0})\left(  d-\frac{1}{4}b^{2}+\frac{1}{3}c\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: FYI there seems to be some minor miscalculations in this formula, but the idea is certainly correct!

Comment: $$\frac{1}{f(x)}'=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}$$, hence the final factorization with $(x-x_0)^2$ is not possible , and the undetermined feature of the limit remains.

Comment: It was just a misprint. The b's cancel out and there is no undetermined form. I corrected it.

Comment: I think the definition for $c$ needs fixing.

Comment: yes. Thanks. I changed it

Comment: Great work @Gio67. 

P.S : the $c$ should be defined differently

Comment: BTW , the final result is $$\frac{1}{24}\left(2f''(x_0)f(x_0)-f'(x_0)^2\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, we can let $x_0=0$, and let
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \frac{1}{f(u)} \, du.$$
We note that since $f$ is positive, we have $g(0) \neq 0$.
We then have
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(xg(x))'} = \frac{1}{xg'(x)  + g(x)},$$
and
$$f(0) = \frac{1}{g(0)}.$$
Therefore we can express the limit as
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\log\left(\frac{g(x)}{\sqrt{g(0)(xg'(x)  + g(x))}}\right)}{(xg(x))^2}.$$
Now we apply L'Hopital's rule and do some algebraic manipulation to get:
$$\frac{g'(0)^2 - \frac12 g''(0)g(0)}{2g(0)^4}.$$

I've done a few example calculations so it should check out.

Comment: $$g'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{1}{f(u)}du}+\frac{1}{xf(x)}$$ What would be the value of $g'(0)$ ?

Comment: Take the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$.  It should exist.  Try it with some example for $f$.

Comment: I would like a generalized formula. What would be the limit in terms of $f$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
f(x)=\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x-x_0)}
$$
Then we have
$$
\begin{align}
g(x)&=\frac{f(x_0)}{f(x+x_0)}\\
g'(x)&=-\frac{f(x_0)\,f'(x+x_0)}{f(x+x_0)^2}\\
g''(x)&=f(x_0)\frac{2f'(x+x_0)^2-f(x+x_0)\,f''(x+x_0)}{f(x+x_0)^3}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{\log\left(\frac1{x-x_0}\int_{x_0}^x\frac{\sqrt{f(x)f(x_0)}}{f(u)}\,\mathrm{d}u\right)}{\left(\int_{x_0}^x\frac1{f(u)}\,\mathrm{d}u\right)^2}\\
&=f(x_0)^2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\left(\frac1{\sqrt{g(x)}}\frac1x\int_0^xg(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\right)}{\left(\int_0^xg(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\right)^2}\\
&=f(x_0)^2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\left(\frac1{\sqrt{g(x)}}\frac1x\int_0^x\left(1+g'(0)u+\frac{g''(0)}2u^2+O\!\left(u^3\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\right)}{\left(\int_0^x\left(1+O\!\left(u\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\right)^2}\\
&=f(x_0)^2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\left(\frac{1+\frac{g'(0)}2x+\frac{g''(0)}6x^2+O\left(x^3\right)}{1+\frac{g'(0)}2x+\left(\frac{g''(0)}4-\frac{g'(0)^2}8\right)x^2+O\left(x^3\right)}\right)}{\left(x+O\!\left(x^2\right)\right)^2}\\
&=f(x_0)^2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(\frac{g'(0)^2}8-\frac{g''(0)}{12}\right)x^2+O\!\left(x^3\right)}{x^2+O\!\left(x^3\right)}\\[6pt]
&=f(x_0)^2\left(\color{#C00}{\frac{g'(0)^2}8}\color{#090}{-\frac{g''(0)}{12}}\right)\\[6pt]
&=f(x_0)^2\left(\color{#C00}{\frac{f'(x_0)^2}{8\,f(x_0)^2}}\color{#090}{-\frac{2f'(x_0)^2}{12\,f(x_0)^2}+\frac{f''(x_0)}{12\,f(x_0)}}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac{-f'(x_0)^2+2f''(x_0)\,f(x_0)}{24}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for correcting the missed $2$ Canardini!